# how to add custom payment mehtod for OpenCart,

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart, payment

The payment methods of my country are not listed in OpenCart Extensions.I want to create one from scratch.Is it possible to write one or I have to use ones comes with OpenCart extensions?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be able to implement and use your own "payment method" since OpenCart is open sourced. Just need to spend some time figuring out how it connects.
Well regarding your own "payment method", normally you have to do it through a Gateway. PAYPAL is one of the easiest gateway to be implemented in PHP. Just have a try with their [API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/gs_PayPalAPIs/) and some of the [sample codes](http://paypal.github.io/sdk/sample-apps/).
There are a lot of other options though. [This](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/04/11/taking-credit-card-payments-online-whats-involved/) may be helpful.